# Conservation of Momentum Paradox Thought-Experiment (Please Explain)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

**The Device:**
Imagine a physical system involving two circular rings of distinct inner and outer radii, but equal in inertia. The smaller ring is superimposed inside the inner radius of the larger ring. These two rings have negligible thickness and are allowed to freely rotate about an axis going through their center of mass, lying on the horizontal x-y plane. The axis of rotation is orthogonal to the face of the rings.

Now, imagine a long rod along the z-axis attached to both rings, connecting them together by acting as the "spine" of this ring-system. This rod is attached symmetrically through their center of masses along the z-axis. When the rod moves along the z-axis, it moves both rings translationally along with it. The rings are still allowed to freely rotate as mentioned previously, but their faces can no longer rotate because of the rod.

On the other end of the rod, some distance away, is attached a large square plate whose length or width (being the same) cannot be less than the outer radius of the largest ring on the other end of the rod; it is at least slightly longer. Both faces of the two-ring system and the square plate are orthogonal.

**The Phenomenon:**
Imagine that potential energy is introduced into the system. After the full amount of potential energy is stored into the system, we will call this system a close-system for energy whose total energy will be equal to the stored potential energy.

The energy is stored by, e.g., two loaded mechanical box springs. One is placed sitting tangent outside of the smaller inner ring to the right and the other is placed tangent outside of the larger ring to the left. Suppose that each ring has at least one groove or a tiny paddle that the springs are sitting on. There are two balls sitting on the other end of each spring of same mass.

Now the system is given energy by compressing the springs together, pushing the ball down closer the groove of each ring. Then, in an instant, the springs are released turning all the potential energy into kinetic energy. (The springs had negligible mass and no longer become relevant once released).

All net forces and torques in this system during the release were zero, e.g., the force on the ball was the same yet opposite in direction to the tangential force on the ring. The torques on both rings were also the same but opposing in direction. Their new angular momentum is the same in magnitude but are anti-parallel because they have the same inertias, consistant with Newton's Laws. **Energy and Angular Momentum are both conserved in this thought-experiment**

**Has Linear Momentum Been Conserved?**

The whole two-ring, rod and plate system is NOT moving translationally because no force had acted through it's center of mass.

Up to this point, in terms of linear momentum, only the balls carry linear momentum. The whole system, if you include the balls is net positive for linear momentum, which is perplexing considering that it started with zero linear momentum before the energy release. This was true for angular momentum--it started with zero and ended with net zero, but not linear momentum. Now let us continue this thought-experiment because the balls are moving in space right now.

To show what this means fully, the balls are headed for a collision course to the square plate at the end of the rod. Let's suppose that they make an "inelastic collision" with the plate, such that linear momentum is conserved. The balls are now stuck to the plate and all their momentum has been transferred to the entire mass of the contraption. The entire system is now slowly moving forward with net linear momentum!

**Please tell me what went wrong in this experiment**

Comment: Hi James, I gave up on your question because I wasn't confident that I properly understood all the arrangements you were trying to describe. It would help if you could upload diagrams.

Comment: Same here. I can’t tell how everything is arranged and moving. In any case, when you make something overly complicated like this you can get confused. Momentum is, of course, conserved. You just confused yourself (and me)

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: If one ring is larger, and another ring is smaller, and the balls are ejected from each ring in parallel but opposite directions, _either_ the magnitude of the force induced on the rest of the system can be the same, _or_ the magnitude torque induced on the rest of the system can be the same. Both cannot be true, unless both are 0.

Comment: @notovny No, they are ejected in the same direction. Both the magnitude and direction all forces are zero and and all torques are zero. There is never an instance where either one of them is non-zero in this example.

Comment: _You need to add a picture to this question. that shows the setup you're assuming._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description is super-complicated, so I could be misunderstanding the setup. But I believe that the mistake is here:

> The whole two-ring, rod and plate system is NOT moving translationally because no force had acted through it's center of mass.

It doesn’t matter if a force acts through the center of mass. The center of mass accelerates according to $\Sigma \vec F = m \vec a$ regardless of where the force acts. The springs accelerate both objects that they are attached to.

A (much) simpler example that illustrates the idea is a force applied to the end of a rigid rod perpendicular to the axis. Such a force will cause the rod to rotate and to translate, as required by Newton’s 2nd law. You can observe this on an air hockey table or similar low-friction setup

Comment: I've thought about that too, but the forces acting on the rings are tangential forces The rings are free to rotate. It should only cause rotation, not translational motion.

Comment: @JamesThompson that is not correct. Tangential forces still follow Newton’s 2nd law. I have added a paragraph explaining

Comment: I was considering a case of tangential forces on a circle that sum to zero causing rotation and no translation so my statement is indeed correct in such instance. I looked up your example in detail and it is correct and familiar, but it does not apply. The ball will have the same momentum whether the release in tangent or centered, but the rings will not have the same linear momentum in both cases. The only way to model such behavior is a closed system for angular momentum of the ring and ball.

Comment: @JamesThompson do the two balls go off in opposite directions? Your description is super confusing and over-complicated (again a drawing is recommended), but I envisioned the balls both going away in the same direction. In any case, your quoted statement is wrong "The whole two-ring, rod and plate system is NOT moving translationally because no force had acted through it's center of mass." Where the forces act is irrelevant. If you have multiple opposite forces then indeed $\Sigma F = 0$ so $a=0$, but it has nothing to do with the location of the force. The 2nd law holds for tangential forces

Comment: Okay, so you are suggesting that my statement of the whole system not moving is wrong. And, that it is in fact moving in the opposite direction of the balls in accordance with Newton's Laws so that there is not net change in momentum. And once the balls collide with the plate the system stops entirely. That's the only way out it seems. But location of the force does seem to matter. Let me explain in next comment, then I'm going to conclude this thread.

Comment: Let's just take one ring and one ball system. That's it. Same thing happens with the release of the spring. Don't you think that if you had the exact same impulse between the ball and the tangent of the ring, and you had the exact same impulse between the ball and CM of the ring, that the ring would have a different linear momentum and that the ball would have the same linear momentum in both cases? For the tangent, the ring would have both angular and linear momentum. For the CM, it would be all linear momentum.

Comment: @JamesThompson if the impulse is the same then the change of momentum will be the same, regardless of the location. However, you are probably not recognizing how challenging it could be to apply the same impulse. If you simply take two identical springs and compress them identically and apply them to identical rings, a spring at the CM will provide substantially more impulse than one at the edge. You may want to post a new question, as it is difficult to explain in the limitations of a comment

Answer (score 0):

"*Okay, so you are suggesting that my statement of the whole system not moving is wrong. And, that it is in fact moving in the opposite direction of the balls in accordance with Newton's Laws so that there is not net change in momentum. And once the balls collide with the plate, the system stops entirely. That's the only way out it seems.*"

Comment: Welcome to [physics.se]! If the other answer sufficiently answers your question, it's better to accept it; that marks the question as 'concluded'.